# Changing the order of integration for $\int_{1}^2\int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

If f is a continuous and positive function, exchange the order of integration appropriately.
$$\int_{1}^2\int_{2-x}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx$$
Note that $x \in [1,2]$ and $y\in [2-x,\sqrt{2x-x^2}]$

if $y = 2-x \implies x=2-y$ so our new lower limit is $ 2-y $, however I don't know how to calculate the new upper limit, can someone help me

[image]

Comment: Did you try sketching out the two curves? Always a first step

Comment: Note that (generally), the bounds $2-x$ and $\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ can intersect, so your phrasing "the new upper limit" is optimistic and not necessarily accurate.  (When they intersect, you split the region of integration into intervals so that you always integrate from the lower bound to the upper bound on each interval.)

Comment: Yes, I have already plotted it, I have already edited the question with the plot

Comment: Hopefully the hints I provided below are enough.  Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints that should take you there:  First sketch the curves.  [image]

So the region is the part above the green line and below the blue line  When changing to $dxdy$, we now want to go from left function to right function instead of higher function to lower function,  so you need the green line as a function of $x=something in y$  and then the blue line as well.  When you go to solve for $x$ in $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ you will have to complete the square,  then when you take the square root you will get a $\pm$.   Make sure you pick the right positive or negative to get the right half blue curve, not the left.

after that,  your y bounds are easy, they go from 0 to 1.

Comment: I think I have solved it, the change in the order of integration looks like: $$\int_1^2\int_{2-y}^{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}f(x,y)dxdy$$   that as $ 1 + \sqrt {1-y ^ 2} $ said is the right part

Comment: Inner bounds are fine.  You need to change the 1 and 2 on the outer integral, as you need the $y$ values not $x$ values

Comment: Sure, the limits must be 0 and 1

Comment: And you're done!